# Point normal equation of plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, plane-curves

Im doing an homeassignment in linear algebra!
This is the question I'm having problems with!

> The plane M contains two lines;
>
> **l1** : (x, y, z) = t(2, −1, 0), t ∈ **R**,
>
> **l2** : (x, y, z) = t(0, 1, 2), t ∈ **R**.
>
> Determine a point-normal equation of the plane M and compute the acute angle between M and the line;
>
> **l3 : (x, y, z) = t(2, 1, 1), t ∈ R. (ON-system assumed.)**

I have taken the crossproduct of l1 and l2 and got that computed to be: (-2, -4, 2) , which in my understanding is n (the normal of the plane?) But them I am stuck.I can't understand if the plane contains fully the two lines, or only points from the lines?? From what i've learned two lines are too much information for a plane in 3-dim? Three points or one line and one point is enough.?? Also why is the lines only described in parametric (x, y, x) = t(0,1,2). What does the parameter exactly mean, is it a direction vector? usually is lines not described with: {x-3 = t, y+6 = 3t, z+5 = 2t}...I am probably not understanding the concept completely, I have been trying to do this question for hours now and I really need some help to get me going. 
I also know that for shortest distance I want the angle of line and plane to be pi/2, since then cos(theta) will be 0. I can probably also use this somehow??
Grateful if I could get some concrete tips and tricks how to do this and what it all really means...

***From where do I get the point p0 and p, are they from the lines in the plane or from the line i will compute the acute angle of l-M??***

***Have I calculated n (normal) to plane correctly??***

***Why are the lines only described in parameter t??***

Comment: Maybe I could calculate the acute angel from cos(phi) = |m||n|/squareroot(m^2)*squareroot(n^2) ?? But how do I get the equation of the plane in point normal form? Is'nt it better to have it in the form Ax+By+Cz = D ??

Comment: Please use block-quotes (`> block-quoted text`) to distinguish what is asked in the assignment what are your thoughts. See example above, but I didn't know if **l3** is part of the answer or part of the question (see http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)

Comment: Oh sorry. L3 is part of the question and not the answer. I'll try to fix my writing style :) so it's more understandable. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it's generally impossible to find a plane that contains two given lines. In fact, it's possible only if the two given lines intersect. Fortunately, the two lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ in your problem **do** intersect; in fact, they intersect at the origin $(0,0,0)$.

To see this, look at the equations. The line $l_1$ has equation $(x,y,z) = t(2,-1,0)$. This says that every point $(x,y,z)$ on the line is some multiple ($t$) of the vector $(2,-1,0)$. In particular, when $t=0$, you get $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$. So, the line passes through the origin and has direction $(2,-1,0)$.

If we let $\mathbf{p}_0 = (0,0,0)$, then $l_1$ has equation
$$
(x,y,z) = \mathbf{p}_0 +t(2,-1,0) = (0+2t, 0-t, 0)
$$
which might be the kind of line equation you were expecting.

Similarly, the line $l_2$ passes through the origin and has direction $(0,1,2)$.

The plane containing $l_1$ and $l_2$ has normal vector $\mathbf{n} = (-2, -4,2)$, which you correctly computed as a cross product, and it also passes through the origin. So its equation is $(x,y,z).\mathbf{n} = 0$, i.e. $-2x-4y+2z=0$. The equation $x +2y -z =0$ is simpler, and gives you the same plane.

To get the angle between line $l_3$ and the plane, we can get the angle between the line and the plane normal, and then subtract from 90 degrees.

The line $l_3$ is in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{v} = (2,1,1)$, and the plane normal is $\mathbf{n} = (-2, -4,2)$. The angle $\theta$ between these two vectors is given by
$$
\cos\theta = \frac
{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{n}}
{|\mathbf{v}| \cdot |\mathbf{n}|}
= \frac
{(2)(-2) + (1)(-4)+(1)(2)}
{\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2}\sqrt{(-2)^2 + (-4)^2 + 2^2}} =
\frac{-6}{12}
$$
Then the angle between the plane and $l_3$ is $90- \theta$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful. Now I know that I was on the right path with planes being described by 3 points and that I computed the correct crossproduct for n of the plane. I was not completely sure that it was the right one, but I assumed so, since with my information that was what I could do. I'm going to read this thoroughly and see if I can finish this. If I still have something unclear and undone, I'll post some more questions til I understand it fully. Thank you again for taking time to help me :)

Comment: I computed the point normal form as: (-2, -4, 2)(-2t, 0, 2t) = (4t, 0, 4t). Is this right. I want to compute the angle but I am a little unsure, do I use cos(theta) = (2,1,1)*(-2,-4.2)/ (point normal eq. of plane?)

Comment: The equation of the plane is $-2x -4y +2z = 0$. Not entirely sure what you mean by "point-normal" form.

Comment: Regarding the angle, see the addtions to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take the cross product of **l1** and **l2** directions to find the plane normal vector (non-unit vector)

$$ \vec{n} = \vec{e}_1 \times \vec{e}_2 = (2,-1,0) \times (0,1,2) = (-2,-4,2) $$

The point-normal equation for a plane is $$\vec{n} \cdot (\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0) =0$$ which works of any scalar multiple of $\vec{n}$ (no need to normalize to a unit vector) and $\vec{r}_0$ as *any* point on the plane. Might as well take $t=0$ for **l1** to give $\vec{r}_0 = (0,0,0)$. So the plane equation is

$$ -2x-4y+2z=0 $$

The acute angle $\theta$ of the plane to the line **l3** is found by noting that it is equal to 90° minus the angle $\varphi$ between the line and the plane normal. This is found by the inner product rule

$$ \vec{n} \cdot \vec{e} = | \vec{n}| |\vec{e}| \cos\varphi $$

with $\vec{n}=(-2,-4,2)$ and $\vec{e}=(2,1,1)$

$$\varphi = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{\vec{n}\cdot\vec{e}}{|\vec{n}| |\vec{e}|} \right) = \left( \frac{(-2,-4,2)\cdot(2,1,1)}{ (2\sqrt{6})(\sqrt{6})} \right) = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{-6}{12} \right) = 120°$$

Since the angle is > 90° we have to flip the direction of the line to get $\vec{e} = (-2,-1,-1)$ and

$$ \varphi = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{6}{12} \right) = 30° $$

So the angle of the line **l3** to the plane is $$\boxed{\theta = 90° - \varphi = 60°}$$

Comment: How do I know i need to flip the direction of the line? Can I just do that without changing the information somehow. I would never have thought of that. And also cos^-1(6/12) = 60 degrees right, so then theta = 90-60 = 30 degrees?? :) Thanx for this, very helpful!

Comment: If you don't flip the answer will be -30° which doesn't have any physical meaning. You can flip the direction of the line, or take the absolute value of the angle (the result would be the same). Yes, on the other points.